# IvyIdea plugin - does not resolve dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, ivy

I am using IntelliJ, added IvyIdea plugin and now trying to resolve dependencies for a project (Ant build) using IvyIdea but getting error about "UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES". I have downloaded and configured Ivy and Ant.

I can resolve and build the project using Ant command line but not via IDE. I can see the ~.ivy2\cache folder has got all the dependencies resolved which it is complaining about.

I have configured "Facets" for all modules to map to the correct Ivy settings and build properties files. Does anyone know if there is anything else I can try?

[image]

One thing I found now in the logs,

```
loadData of pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT of rootConf=default
    using default to resolve pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT
default: Checking cache for: dependency: pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT {default-ext=[default]}
don't use cache for pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT: changing=true
don't use cache for pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT: changing=true
    local (useCacheOnly) : no ivy file found for pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT
main: Checking cache for: dependency: pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT {default-ext=[default]}
don't use cache for pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT: changing=true
don't use cache for pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT: changing=true
    shared (useCacheOnly) : no ivy file found for pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT
don't use cache for pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT: changing=true
    public (useCacheOnly) : no ivy file found for pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT
WARN:   module not found: pentaho-kettle#kettle-core;7.1-SNAPSHOT
WARN: ==== local: tried
WARN: ==== shared: tried
WARN: ==== public: tried
```

I have made sure I am using correct Ivy settings and build properties but still it gives the same errors.

Answer (score 5):

I also tried to work with Pentaho using IntelliJ. It is quite a job, because a lot of code is set up using Apache Ivy and Ant, and the rest is done with Maven.

What worked for me is the following..

## Compiling in IntelliJ

- Make sure the normal build works from the command line.
- Install the latest IvyIdea plugin in IntelliJ
- Now open IntelliJ, and just open the pentaho-kettle directory without importing anything.
- Select File -> New -> Module from existing sources, then select the "assembly" directory.
- Let it import the sources, but deselect any libraries it finds. It should also automatically find the ivy.xml and add the IvyIdea facet.
- After the import click on "assembly" in the Project browser, then press F4 to go to the module settings.
- Click the "Sources" tab for the module and check if there is a directory called "res", "packages-res" or anything else nonstandard that means resources - EXCEPT build-res (ignore those). Click on those directories, then click "Mark as - resource" above the tree.
- Click the "IvyIdea" facet for the module, and configure the following:

  - select "Use module specific settings" (make it checked). Then select "Use your own", and select the ivysettings.xml file from the "assembly" directory.
  - Click the "properties" tab, then "Add file", and select the build.properties file from the assembly directory.
- Repeat this process for the other main modules, like core and engine and everything else where you can find a ivy.xml file. This is a lot of work, as there are many modules. You can use the following command (linux) to find all modules:

  ```
  find . -name 'ivy.xml'
  ```
- Once done let IvyIdea resolve all dependencies by clicking pentaho-kettle (the main directory) in the project explorer, then right-click -> IvyIdea -> resolve all dependencies. Make sure you have lots of coffee and lunch ready because it will take forever.
- Under plugins find the "pom.xml" file there. On the right side of IntelliJ open the "Maven Projects" view (or use View -> Tool Windows -> Maven projects).
- In that Maven view, click the green + to add a pom, and navigate to plugins/pom.xml. This lets IntelliJ import the rest of the plugins. This again takes a while.
- Now, click on the UI module in the Project Explorer, then press F4. Click the "dependencies" tab, then the green "+" on the right and select "Module dependency".
- In the list that follows: select everything, then press ok. This makes the ui module have a classpath that includes the plugins, so that spoon will find the thingies when starting.

After this IntelliJ should be able to build the modules added: press ctrl+f9 to check.

## Running the compiled result

To get this thing to run is yet another bag of fun. I am running Linux, so the instructions here apply to that. YMMV on other operating systems or Windows.

- In the project explorer, find the "Spoon" class in the UI project (or press CTRL+N then Spoon).
- Find the main method and press the green button in the margin before it. This will try to run main, and will die horribly - but IntelliJ now has made a run configuration ;)
- Open the run configuration (Run -> Edit Configurations).
- Under "VM Options" add the following (click the little box to the right to get a big input field):

  ```
  -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
  -Djava.library.path=./../libswt/linux/x86_64/
  -DKETTLE_HOME=
  -DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=
  -DKETTLE_USER=
  -DKETTLE_PASSWORD=
  -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=
  -DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=
  -DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=
  -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_CLASSES=org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.gpload.GPLoadMeta,org.pentaho.di.core.database.PALODatabaseMeta,org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.palo.cellinput.PaloCellInputMeta,org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.palo.celloutput.PaloCellOutputMeta,org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.palo.diminput.PaloDimInputMeta,org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.palo.dimoutput.PaloDimOutputMeta,org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.hl7input.HL7InputMeta,org.pentaho.di.job.entries.hl7mllpack.HL7MLLPAcknowledge,org.pentaho.di.job.entries.hl7mllpin.HL7MLLPInput,org.pentaho.di.starmodeler.StarModelerSpoonPlugin,org.pentaho.di.core.market.Market,org.pentaho.di.job.entries.palo.JobEntryCubeCreate.PaloCubeCreate,org.pentaho.di.job.entries.palo.JobEntryCubeDelete.PaloCubeDelete,org.pentaho.di.core.database.OpenERPDatabaseMeta,org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.openerp.objectinput.OpenERPObjectInputMeta,org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.openerp.objectoutput.OpenERPObjectOutputMeta,org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.openerp.objectdelete.OpenERPObjectDeleteMeta
  ```
- These parameters were stolen from spoon.sh, the script that usually starts Spoon. You might want to check that file if you still have trouble.
- Set the working directory to pentaho-kettle/assembly/package-res
- Add the following environment variables using the button after "Environment variables:[image: Environment variables to set for Linux]

This should make it possible to run Spoon. You might get quite some messages in the console, and Spoon can take more than a minute to start (on my quite fast machine), so be patient ;)

Good luck ;)

Comment: this seems to be outdated, kettle now fully depends on maven. Have you configured the latest version in intellij ? you can please refer to my question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282976/running-pentaho-spoon-ui-in-intellij

Comment: By using the above idea and not using (ivy/ant) since maven is used now, I added modules to the UI module from project-structure - dependencies.

I see there are cyclic dependencies

while running Spoon.Java I see error saying `annotation processing are not allowed on cyclic dependencies.`

If I don't add the module and I just run Spoon.Java
I see a lot of error saying
`ClassDefNotFound com.google.api....`

Comment: Thanks @udbhavgovil for your comments. As you can see from the date of posting this was done in 2017, and at that time this version of Kettle was compiled using Ivy. So it is outdated for the *current* version of Kettle which indeed uses Maven, but not for anyone needing the older version yet.
I also think the answer might still be useful for others using Ivy and having trouble.

Comment: Right, since you have managed to get it running through intellij, can you please take a look at this question and see if you could help for the current version.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282976/running-pentaho-spoon-ui-in-intellij