# Running pentaho spoon UI in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have been trying to setup dev environment for [pentaho kettle](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle) but had some trouble to run `Spoon.Java` and I see lot of `ClassNotFoundException com.google.api.....`

Maybe because the dependencies of plugins package is not under the class path of the UI package to run the spoon application.

How can I effeciently setup dev environment and run Spoon tool from intellij for development and debugging ?

There are [older articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965473/ivyidea-plugin-does-not-resolve-dependencies/44325579#44325579%5Chttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965473/ivyidea-plugin-does-not-resolve-dependencies/44325579%2344325579%5C) but it seems to be outdated since *ivy/ant* is not used anymore, only *Maven* seems to be used.